How can I view the automatically created channel's live broadcast list using YouTube API v3?
I want to check the list of live broadcasts in the LOL game section of the game category through YouTube API.
I live in Korea, and the URL is as follows.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZtmNrG53nmbq-Ww2VJrxEQ (It is a channel Auto-generated by YouTube)
I ran the API from this page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).
Value is part=snippet, channelId=UCZtmNrG53nmbq-Ww2VJrxEQ, eventType=live, type=video
but, I got the value as follows.
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "jY03jGgN1g_xKk8RSHyjN_PoL8I",
  "regionCode": "KR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0;
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}

There is clearly something live broadcasting, but it passes an empty value.
I don't know what I did wrong.
I think the search API doesn't support auto-generated channels.
I want collect live streams data list.

You want My region or Worldwide or both lives, see https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZtmNrG53nmbq-Ww2VJrxEQ/live?

@BenjaminLoison it would be good to have both options, tbh.

@Mauricio Arias Olave you are just assuming @김기현 opinion or you are also interested in this feature? I am just trying to minimize the work I have to do to meet the needs of people in my open-source YouTube operational API, see https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/287.

@BenjaminLoison I'm interested in the feature. I'm aware of you open-source operational API, hence, my comment. I was expecting your response.

For My region parsing https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZtmNrG53nmbq-Ww2VJrxEQ/live source code is enough, but for Worldwide it requires Protobuf manipulation to make it, cleanly in my opinion. You would like to have your own instance having a Protobuf dependency like https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/compare/protobuf_and_authentication_for_community_post_poll_vote_details_retrieval#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5 or you would be fine using the potentially unstable official instance https://yt.lemnoslife.com?

Unfortunately, the YouTube API doesn't work as the main website.
I've tested and for auto-generated channels, YouTube API does not return data.
You have to used another ways for get this information.

thank you for the reply.
What is annother ways?? (examples crawling?)

Web-scraping is a workaround.
